# timeout errors from Lambda when trying to access an Amazon RDS DB instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am writing a Python app to run as lambda function and want to connect to an RDS DB instance without making it publicly accessible.

The RDS DB instance was already created under the default VPC with security group "sg-abcd".

So I have:

- created a lambda function under the same default VPC
- created a role with the following permission AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole and assigned it to the lambda function as in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html
- set sg-abcd as the lambda function's security group
- added sg-abcd as source in the security group's inbound rules
- added the CIDR range of the lambda function's subnet as source in the security group's inbound rules

However, when I invoke the lambda function it times out.

I can connect to the RDS DB from my laptop (after setting my IP as source in the sg's inbound rules), so I now that it is not an authentication problem. Also, for the RDS DB "Publicly Accessible" is set to "Yes".

Here's part of the app's code (where I try to connect):

```
rds_host  = "xxx.rds.amazonaws.com"

port = xxxx

name = rds_config.db_username

password = rds_config.db_password

db_name = rds_config.db_name


logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=rds_host, database=db_name, user=name, password=password, connect_timeout=20)

except psycopg2.Error as e:

    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to PostgreSQL instance.")

    logger.error(e)

    sys.exit()
```

I really can't understand what I am missing. Any suggestion is welcomed, please help me figure it out!

Edit: the inbound rules that I have set look like this:

```
Security group rule ID: sgr-123456789
Type Info: PostgreSQL
Protocol Info: TPC
Port range Info: 5432
Source: sg-abcd OR IP or CIDR range
```

Comment: Are lambda and rds in the same subnet?

Comment: Lambda is in one of the three subnets of the RDS.

Comment: All I can suggest is open everything thing up allowing all ports and all services in the SG, and make sure that works first. Then add tighter rules after that.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. I was hoping there was something evidently missing in my setup, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This [document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-lambda-to-an-rds-instance/) should help you out. Just make sure to get the suggestions for your specific scenario, whether the lambda function and the RDS instance are in the same VPC or not.

In my case I have the lambda function and the RDS instance in the same VPC and also both have the same subnets and SGs. But just make sure to follow the instructions in that document for the configurations needed for each scenario.